# How to version control text with lines that are one paragraph long?

Tags: text, version-control, markdown, long-lines

I want to implement simple version control in my app. But to make it any useful the lines must be split somehow so users don't have to hunt for their changes. It there preferred way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps
[`fmt`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fmt)

```
Usage: fmt [-WIDTH] [OPTION]... [FILE]...
Reformat each paragraph in the FILE(s), writing to standard output.
The option -WIDTH is an abbreviated form of --width=DIGITS.

  -w, --width=WIDTH         maximum line width (default of 75 columns)
```